# Convert a string back into Origional Format

Tags: java, encoding, decode

I convert a byte array `msg` into a string `encodedmsg` withe the formatting `ISO-8859-1` like this:
`String encodedmsg = new String(msg, "ISO-8859-1");`
I cant work out how to now go from my string `encodedmsg` back to the byte array `msg`, essentially revert what I do in the first place. Any help would be much appreaciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get back  `byte[]` as follows:

```
byte[] arr = encodedmsg.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] msg = "hello".getBytes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(msg));
        String encodedmsg = new String(msg, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println(encodedmsg);
        byte[] arr = encodedmsg.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
hello
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new String(encodedmsg.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```